# Webcam Integration with php

Tags: php, webcam

I need to integrate the Web cam to the application. I need to take the user profile picture using the web cam.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot acces the webcam from HTML, not even using JavaScript. I think your only option is to use Flash for this. (PHP has little to do with it...)

Comment: Oh i see.. Thanks for sharing your knowledge. I have seen same reply's in some forums also.

I check, how can i implement that with flash.

Thanks again. :)

Comment: This information is outdated. Accessing a webcam from JavaScript is possible nowadays.

Answer (score 1):

You should write program that run on client side and response to the server. I don't think PHP can do this job.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Flash, ActiveX or Java applet seems to be the only options to access user's webcam